# How to add to an array in a database and get back each array and display it

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

How can I add a value into an array in a database row, and then later on, when I want to get values of the array, simply display each different array value on a new line?

Also, how do arrays work in mysql and how to get the value of it?

Comment: Why not using an ORM? Instead of using arrays, you can use objects. There is open source ORM in php like Doctrine.

Comment: @Anthony I mean what I say, so basically, access and write to it from a database and php

Comment: Use serialize data then. Get DB row -> unserialize it -> add element to array -> serialize it -> update DB row

Comment: How can I do that @Anthony? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filed testField has serialized data.

```
$arrayData = array('one','two','three');
$serializedData = serialize($arrayData);
```

Mysql insertion:

```
insert INTO table ('testField') Values ($serializedData);
```

To get data:

```
select testField from table where id=1
```

You are getting here some string value. Then you should unserialize this string to get array:

```
$arrayData = unserialize($selectResultValue);
```

Look here for more details about serialize function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: That looks great! But how does serialized content look like in a database?

Comment: it is just a string like: {O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}

Comment: Don't mention about how it looks like in a DB. Because you shouldn't edit this manually. But if you are going to use filtering by this field then you should normalize DB as @Ollie Jones said.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have a native array data type.  So, your first step is to figure out how you will store the elements of the array in a MySQL table.

Will you store each array element in its own database row?

```
 elem  val
  1    value1
  2    value2
     ...
  n    valuen
```

Or will you store the arraw as a series of concatenated values in a single row, something like this?

```
  values  
  value1,value2,value3,...,valuen
```

In the first case, you can update a single array element easily:

```
  UPDATE array SET val=newValue
   WHERE elem=updatedElement
```

In the second case, you'll have to read the values column, break it out (deserialize it) into an array, change the element or elements you want to change, then gather it up (serialize it) back into a values column, and update your mySQL table. @Anthony pointed this out.

You need to answer the question about how you're storing the array before you can start to figure out how you will update it.

Answer (score 1):

#### save array

```
$foo = array(1,2,3);
mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO some_table ('foo') VALUES ('%s')", serialize($foo));
```

foo will appear as a string `1,2,3` in the database now

#### fetch array

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, foo FROM some_table")
$item = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$foo = $item->foo;
$foo = unserialize($foo);
```

#### add data to array

```
$foo[] = 4;
$foo = array_uniq($foo); // you might want to ensure only unique values
mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE some_table SET foo='%s' WHERE id=%d", serialize($foo), $item->id);
```

foo will appear as a string `1,2,3,4` in the database now